# Disabled booting from hard drive in bios

Tags: boot, usb, uefi, bios

today I was trying to install Manjaro on my Ubuntu laptop from USB. I changed the #1 booting option to booting from USB in the bios thinking that would make my laptop boot from USB. It didn't work, so I got frustrated and disabled booting from hard drive in the BIOS thinking that it would force it to boot from USB.
I restarted and now all I see when I boot is:

`Checking media presence... No media present.`

Pushing ESC to enter boot manager doesn't work.
By pressing random F keys I can access a blue screen where I can boot from IP4, IP6 network controllers and SMI USB Disk.
None of those work. I didn't unmount the USB since the incident. I don't mind resetting or losing data.

Any insight on how to fix this?

Comment: Read the documentation for your computer's motherboard. Your BIOS is your motherboard's firmware and is independent from any operating system.

Comment: How did you write the ISO to the USB drive?

Comment: The Bios settings screen is not the boot device selection menu. They are accessed with two different keys or key combinations. If you go into the Bios again you should be able to enable the hard disk again. Since you disabled the HDD (and I don't think you can do that from the boot selection menu) and since, for some reason your USB is not being recognised, the boot menu won't find a boot device to boot from.

Comment: I wrote the ISO using balenaEtcher. It said it wrote without any issues.

Comment: I solved the problem by pressing DEL(I found the key in my laptop's manual) when my laptop was booting, which opened bios. Thanks to all of you for help!

Comment: Hey @cyjo! Please do answer your question as it will be helpful to the community. I advise you to read this article for more information: https://askubuntu.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 0):

In order to re-enable booting from hard drive do the following:
Turn off your computer.
Turn on and start pressing the key to enter bios (you will find it in your computer's manual or on the manufacturer's website. In my case it's DEL).
Go to booting options and re-enable hard drive in the bios.
Reboot.